# Placing Items in a TreeView Side by Side

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, treeview

I am trying to create a TreeView where each element in the tree contains a CheckBox and a ComboBox side by side. I am able to generate the ComboBoxes in the TreeView and have experimented with using another TreeView but this still does not produce the output I would like ( I want the CheckBox and ComboBox to appear side by side, not with one below the other like I have managed in the code below) Is there a way that I can achieve this? Below is the code that I am using now, it is very simple. I am simply adding items to a TreeView, is there a way that I can place two items side by side in the TreeView?

```
 TreeViewItem foo = new TreeViewItem();
        foo.Header = groupName.Text;
        treeView1.Items.Add(foo);
        Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
        dlg.Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt";
        dlg.FilterIndex = 0;
        dlg.Multiselect = true;
        dlg.RestoreDirectory = true;
        dlg.Title = "Read .txt Log File";
        if (dlg.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            newList = new DynoFileList(groupName.Text); 
            foreach (String file in dlg.FileNames)
            {
                TreeViewItem foo2 = new TreeViewItem();
                DynoFile testing = new DynoFile(file,groupName.Text); // Creating a new Dyno run file
                CheckBox test = new CheckBox();
                ComboBox ColorSelect = new ComboBox();
                test.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(BoxClicked);
                test.Content = testing.getName();
                foo.Items.Add(test);
                foo.Items.Add(foo2); // This does not quite produce the output that I desire, I was the items to be side by side, not cascaded in any way. The second TreeView is not absolutely necessary
                foo2.Items.Add(ColorSelect);// This does not quite produce the output I want
                newList.addRun(testing); 
                allBoxes.Add(test);

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a look into DataTemplates in WPF, they are seriosly powerful and will make your life a lot easier.

Specifically have a look into HierarchicalDataTemplates.  There is a [very good article here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikehillberg/archive/2009/10/30/treeview-and-hierarchicaldatatemplate-step-by-step.aspx)

I have also published an article on [DataTemplates over on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28060/WPF-UserControl-DataTemplate) which you'll also find useful.

Comment: To expand on the above answer, DataTemplating in WPF if probably one of the most oft used ways of translating data into UI.  An ItemsControl (which TreeView is subclassed from) contains  your objects (Airplanes, Football Teams, Customers, whatever), but it displays it as a group of, for example, rounded boxes, with some text and a checkbox and a button.  I would recommend reading up on DataTemplating and experiment with it alot to get a good handle on it.  If you are writing a UI that is going to handle anything more than the simplest of items, you will nearly always use a data template.